# Updating a single value in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I have a webpage where I display a list of passenger information as a table. This is the usual stuff: arrival_time, flight number etc.

I've made the table editable so when the user clicks a certain column with information he can edit this column. When he finally clicks confirm I send only the columns that were edited along with value and row number to the view which is suppose to locate the row of the list from the data I sent, find the key and update the original value.

The json values I get from editing a column look like this:

```
[{u'classname': u'flight', u'column': 6, u'value': u'F1521', u'row': 0}, {u'classname': u'flight', u'column': 6, u'value': u'FI521', u'row': 1}]
```

The code I have so far to update the value looks like this:

```
# Original data
query = UploadOrderModel.objects.filter(hashId = receiptNr)
# Gives me a list of dictionaries containing these keys
data  = query.values("office", "reserv", "title","surname","firstN",
                            "arrival", "flight", "transferF", "hotelD", "tour")
# Update
json_dump = json.loads(request.body)
if json_dump:
    for d in json_dump:
        # get row number
        row  = int(d['row'])
        # updates dictionary value at row
        data[row][d['classname']] = d['value']
```

But this does not update the value. I have checked if is getting the correct values to update and it is, so that's not the case, row is correct and if I print out:

```
data[row][d['classname']]
```

I get the element I want to update. Is there anything really obvious I'm missing here.
Should I be making updates to the entire row instead? so update the entire dictionary at 
the current location?

EDIT:

I'm still having problems. First off, i misread your good answer lyschoening. I thought you meant that values() does not return a writeable list, silly me. The saving of the model is done later in the code and works as expected. However I still have the problem of the dictionary at the location I'm trying to update does not update at all :/

Comment: `type(data)` is not `dict`, isn't it?

Comment: correct, data is a list. So say I have row = 0, type(data[0]) is a dict at index 0, so I would have thought doing data[0][key] = newValue?

Comment: I am assuming that you are working with Django. afaik `QuerySet.values()` does return a writable dictionary with values, but changes to that dictionary will not be saved in the model. You have to query the model properly and call the `save()` function when you are done.

Comment: Thank you @lyschoening for clearing this. It all makes sense now :D

Comment: unrelated: don't use the same name for different purposes in the same code unit (`data` is both a queryset and a list in your code)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian good point. I will edit this :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out what was the problem.

django values() does not return a list of dictionaries as it looks but a ValuesQuerySet.
It is therefor not possible to do updates on this list as one would do with a regular list.

All I had to do was turning it into a list of dictionaries:

```
updates = [item for item in data]
```